# Python logging module doesn't work within installed windows service

Tags: python, logging, windows-services, pywin32

Why is it that calls to logging framework within a python service do not produce output to the log (file, stdout,...)?

My python service has the general form:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.FileHandler('out.log')
logger.addHandler(fh)

logger.error("OUTSIDE")

class Service (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "example"
    _svc_display_name_ = "example"
    _svc_description_ = "example"

    def __init__(self,args):
        logger.error("NOT LOGGED")
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
              (self._svc_name_,''))

    def SvcStop(self):

        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        self.stop = True

    def SvcDoRun(self):

        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        # Service Logic
        logger.error("NOT LOGGED EITHER")
        pass
```

The first call to logger.error produces output, but not the two inside the service class (even after installing the service and making sure it is running).

Comment: Are you looking in the correct folder for the log file? Services run in the Windows folder.

Comment: Would setting a absolute path for the output log make a difference?

Comment: actually i set it as an absolute path (not shown in my example). I do see the log file being created and the first logger.error("OUTSIDE") message is there. It's the other two which don't get logged.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that only logging within the actual service loop works with the logging module and the log file ends up in something like `C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\win32`.

I abandoned logging with the logging module for Windows as it didn't seem very effective. Instead I started to use the Windows logging service, e.g. `servicemanager.LogInfoMsg()` and related functions. This logs events to the Windows Application log, which you can find in the Event Viewer (start->run->Event Viewer, Windows Logs folder, Application log).

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the full path of the log file.

e.g.

```
fh = logging.FileHandler('C:\\out.log')
```

Answer (score 0):

actually outside logger initialized twice.

these 2 outside loggers are in different processes. one is the python process and another one is windows-service process.

for some reason, the 2nd one didn't configured success, and inside loggers in this process too. that's why u cant find the inside logs.